# .NET RIA Services - DataService problem

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I downloaded an example of the application based on the .NET RIA services from the article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/22/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-6-poco-and-authentication-provider.aspx
from the "download the full demo files" link.

On my PC (MS VS 2008, SP1, NET RIA Services for vs2008) it is not compilable. I have the following error on attempt to compile application:

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'DataService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Temp\RIA\MyApp.LiveSite\MyApp.Web\WebDataService.svc.cs  12  35  MyApp.Web
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'IDataServiceConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Temp\RIA\MyApp.LiveSite\MyApp.Web\WebDataService.svc.cs  15  46  MyApp.Web
and a lot of others...

Do you know what is a source of these errors? Am I need to install anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed. I believe System.Data.Services namespace is part of .NET 3.5

Additionally, does the project include a reference to System.Data.Services?

Comment: You right, project has references to the System.Data.Services, but references are wrong. I've deleted them and added again - now DataService class (and others) were found.

The only unknown class left - DomainServiceException, guess this is some user-class.

Thanks you, Alan!